# Android listview checkedtextview

Tags: android, android-listview, checkedtextview

I have a problem with an Android app. I'm trying to create a listview containing a textview and a checkedtextview per row. I have done the layout and the adapter and it displays all the items correctly, but the problem I have is the folowing: I can check perfectly the first 7 items(the ones that are visible initialy) but when i scroll down to check one of the folowing item(one that is not visible initialy) i get a null pointer exception. What should I do?

Adapter Code:

```
private class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Orders> {

private ArrayList<Orders> items;

public myAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Orders> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.orderslist_row,
                null);
    }

    Orders o = items.get(position);

    CheckedTextView txtSymbol = (CheckedTextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
    txtSymbol.setText(o.getInstrumentID());

    CheckedTextView txtQuantity = (CheckedTextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView2);
    Double qty = o.getQuantity();
    txtQuantity.setText(FormatNumber.Number(qty, 0));

    if (o.getStatus().toString().equals("Rejected"))
        txtQuantity.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    if (o.getStatus().toString().equals("Active"))
        txtQuantity.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

And OnItemClickCode:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
    long id) {
View v = (View)lstOrders.getChildAt(position);
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView2);
ctv.toggle();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`getChildAt(i)` works off of the set of indexes that are visible. When you scroll and position 3 becomes the first visible row, that has become position 0 for the method. So, at any given moment, you're only allowed up to about an index of 7, if that's how many listview rows can fit on the screen. if you're continuing with this method, there's a way tip the scales how you'd like it, you find out what the first visible row index is and then subtract from the total. the listview has such a method.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        View v = (View)lstOrders.getChildAt(position - lstOrders.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView2);
        ctv.toggle();
}
```

Comment: ty mango, it works, but how can i run through the entire listview(ex. a for loop) and get access to all the checkedtextviews in the list?

Comment: under what conditions do you want to do this? and do you want all of them to do something uniformly? i don't think that continuing with `getChildAt` would be best. better would be to have a collection in your adapter that you can modify. then use if statements for what you want in `getView` based on what the collection reads at the corresponding position.

Comment: I want to do some actions with the items checked for example delete them.

Comment: just the `CheckedTextViews`? for something like that i would have two layout rows. one without that view and one with and decide which layout to show depending on what the collection said.

Comment: for something like that. i'd make the adapter a `BaseAdapter` specifically, and make `getCount()` return an arraylist, of which you can remove row indexes from. then a much easier `notifyDataSetChanged()` call.

Comment: @OpreaSerban can you share the solution. i am trying to do something similar